# Refresh content of control

Tags: c#, wpf

I display an image in a grid, which is higher than the window, so it isn't displayed completely.

```
<Grid Name="grid" Margin="0,0,16,0" Height="1000">
    <Image x:Name="image" Source="BigImage.png"/>
</Grid>
```

Now I manually move the grid by:

```
PlotGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, PlotGrid.Margin.Top - 50, 0, PlotGrid.Margin.Bottom + 50);
```

This moves the grid with the image, but the missing part of the image is still missing.
Is there a way to manually refresh the image?

**Edit:**

I noticed that the problem  also occurs without the grid.

```
<Image x:Name="image" Source="fingerprint.ico" Margin="0,0,16,0" Height="1000"/>
```

When I change the position of the image by setting the margin, the missing part of the image is not updated.

[image]

Comment: you wanna rescale to fit ?

Comment: Try `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>PlotGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, PlotGrid.Margin.Top - 50, 0, PlotGrid.Margin.Bottom + 50));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the image in a canvas has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Image properties :
@Edited

```
 <Image  x:Name="image" Source="BigImage.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,16,0">
```

Comment: @Hense : are you trying to move the grid on top of Image?

Comment: @Henste : Image control's margin property value should be same as Grid control's margin properly value. Margin="0,0,16,0"

Comment: See my edit. The image is placed 50 pixels higher, but the lower 50 pixel of the image are not shown.